# What is the best collection type for a packet queue with a TTL per packet in C

Tags: c, collections, network-protocols

I'm programming part of a communication stack. I want incoming packets to be stored in a queue or just a collection wherein each packet has a certain TTL. The packets are sent to a higher layer, if this is successful an acknowledgment message is sent and that specific packet must removed (even if the TTL hasn't passed). If not the packet is resent.

What is the best collection type to use? ex. Something with a random ID for each packet wich can be used to identify the packet for deletion or re-sending purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For random access and deletion you basically have to use a Map; depending on the implementation it may also allow ordered access.

Comment: Ok i'll see if i can find something, thanks! If u have an example code i wouldn't mind if you shared :)

Comment: [http://elliottback.com/wp/hashmap-implementation-in-c/](This) HashMap implementation seems sound enough, you could use it together with a queue for ordered access (<id, packet> in the map, <id> in the queue). Throw in a sorted list with <TTL, id> and you have every possible access you may want (of course for relatively small number of elements it's simpler to just parse the whole map).

Comment: Thank you! Looks like it will be useful!